# Layout guidelines for TCAN1043DRQ1

Tags: pcb, emc, can, layout, signal-integrity

I am using TCAN1043DRQ1 in my design.

May I know what are the layout guidelines I need to follow.

I checked the datasheet it. It does not say anything about layout guidelines. It tells more about protection.

I have few questions:

1. What is the required trace width for signal lines (RXD, TXD, STB_N, EN, ERR_N, SPLIT)?
2. What is the required trace width for supply lines (VBAT, VCC, VIO)?
3. I know the Z0 of can lines (CANH, CANL) is 120 ohm. May I know is there any width requirement?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CAN bus is very low edge rate. It's highly unlikely that you'll ever have a PCB large enough, to have traces long enough, with such a stackup that the trace impedance will be woefully out of spec.  Just choose a trace width in the right ballpark, no need to order with controlled trace impedance.

Average digital logic traces are in the 50-100 ohms range, typically near or at the minimum design rules for the fab (4/4 mils on thin (4-7 mils) prepreg, 7/7 mils on medium (7-10) prepreg).  This suffices for the logic signals.

Put two such traces side by side, and that's 100-200 ohms differential (they hardly couple together).  If you're on the low side of that range, congratulations, you have a CAN pair!

If the electrical length of that pair is a fraction of a bit time, and the total bus and stub length is still adequate for the given baud rate -- CAN won't care.  It's very robust to poor media.

In the interest of good signal quality, we should of course save error budget where possible, in case other devices perform worse, and to maintain a greater margin when things do break down.  Simply choosing the low end of that range will be fine, and we don't need impedance control for that.  Further, choosing relatively short trace lengths, even when the impedance is woefully mismatched, keeps the total effect low.

Just to put trace length in context: at minimum design rules 7/7 (mils), on a sheet-of-paper-sized PCB, you could draw about 300 zig-zags back and forth, of 11" each, or 84 meters (or slightly different numbers for a proper sheet of A4).  At 65% c, that's 0.43µs, or 43% of a bit-time at 1Mbps.  So, even long buses making long routes around a board (just not doubling back on themselves dozens of times like this!) will hardly have an effect on the fastest CAN (5Mbps?), at least in terms of edge quality.

Keep in mind, trace length adds to overall bus/stub length, which is limited by baud rate.  Common mode chokes also have some electrical length which should be added (but, is rarely if ever specified about the component; it can be estimated from the leakage inductance where available).

As for power supply traces, these don't matter as long as the bypass caps are placed locally, and they can be connected to the device with somewhat wider traces (10-20 mils).  If using inner plane power, place the via(s) nearby -- where, which side of the pad(s), doesn't really matter.  If routing on a signal layer, use adequate width for the current rating.  Which should be pretty low (100s mA at most?) so it doesn't matter much.

Do mind that trace length corresponds to inductance (low frequency equivalent), which can cause bypass capacitors to ring against low-impedance nodes elsewhere in the power distribution network (PDN).  This can be estimated by inspecting the layout, and converted into a simulation to show the frequency response.  A possible outcome of this is adding bulk capacitors (relatively large values (several times the total local bypass) with selected ESR) in strategic locations, to dampen the PDN.

Answer (score 1):

There is no guideline for every detail on a PCB. Sometimes, you have to go with the flow!

For comm line, you can have constraints on impedance, length matching, length but not much else. If your comm line aren't that fast, most likely you don't mind any of those (to any reasonable extent).

For power lines, you often are mostly worried about source impedance (you want them low impedance). So usually a bigger trace is better. Shorter is also better.

Therefore:

> 1)What is the required trace width for signal lines(RXD,TXD,STB_N,EN,ERR_N,SPLIT)

I would use something around 10mil/0.25mm since none of those really have any constraint (except the comm lines maybe).

> 2)What is the required trace width for supply lines.(VBAT,VCC,VIO)

As big as you can. for short distance (entering the chip) you might need to go small, but otherwise, I'd try to be wider then 25mil/0.65mm.

3)I know the Z0 of can lines(CANH,CANL) is 120 ohm.May I know is there any width requirement.

When you have a matched impedance trace, you need to know your PCB stackup to calculate the width. Most PCB manufacturer have tools to calculate the trace width based on impedance.

Since you are working with CAN, here are some other constraint, CAN is a differential signal. Therefore, the length of the CAN bus should be matched in length.

Answer (score 1):

For CAN Bus and UART lines, just don't worry about the trace widths as you'll be complicating things for yourself.

Place the IC as close to the connector/terminal as possible, having the CAN-related pins facing to it. The idea is to keep the traces between the connector/terminal to the IC's CAN-related pins as short as possible.

As for the trace widths in general, I'd make them same width as the suggested footprint pad width.

Answer (score 1):

Have a solid ground. You only need to worry about transmission line effects after ~50MHz so routing should be fine with CAN. You may want to shunt the ESD/transients to chassis ground instead of PCB ground.